# How to compare an enum model attribute in a controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have the following model object:

```
class ModelObj < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum type: [:value_a, :value_b]
end
```

In my controller, I want to check the enum `type` attribute's value, but not sure how. **What is the syntax for a comparison of an enumerable value in a controller?**

Here's some code from a controller that *doesn't work*:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    m = ModelObj.find(...)
    if m.type == :value_a
      # do this ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: what is the value of `m` in the controller?

Comment: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Answer (score 16):

According to the [ActiveRecord::Enum documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), you can access the enum value in various ways. Some examples:

```
m.type     # => 'value_a'
m.value_a? # => true
m.value_b? # => false
```

You presented controller code you said “*doesn’t work*”, could it be that you need to use string comparison instead of symbols?

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I have done to get it working:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    m = ModelObj.find(...)
    if (ModelObj.types[m.type] == ModelObj.types[:value_a])
      # do this ...
    end
  end
end
```

You can see it as the current last example at http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html:

`Conversation.where("status <> ?", Conversation.statuses[:archived])`

But the issue is that it's an ordinal value whereas the m.type is the string value.